# How to write this complex self join

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables with given fields

1. HighSchooler

   - name
   - grade
   - id
2. Likes

   - id1
   - id2

HighSchooler holds info on a high school student and Likes is a relationship table showing who likes who in the high school. Student with id1 likes student with id2.
There are both one way relationships (when John likes Lucy but Lucy doesn't like John) and two way relationships (when Albert likes Sandra and Sandra also likes Albert).

I need a query that returns two columns with the names of those in a two way relationship, i.e if A likes B and B likes A, then a sample result-set would be

```
name | name
A       B
```

I fiddle with it and came up with this query, but i don't understand it and don't think it is optimal.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.name, b.name 
FROM Highschooler a, Highschooler b, Likes l1 
JOIN Likes l2 on l1.ID1=l2.ID2 
WHERE a.ID=l1.ID2 AND b.ID=l1.ID1 AND a.ID=l2.ID1 AND a.ID > b.ID;
```

Comment: The query i provided returns the resultset that i need, but i would be glad if i anyone could provide a simpler one which i can easily understand. Thanks

Comment: It would be nice if you included your fiddle link in your question.

Comment: Can a person like more than one person? If not, there is no need for the second table. You could just a column to the Highschooler table for the id of the person they like.

Comment: Don't mix up the comma list and the explicit JOIN notations in a single query; actually, don't use the comma list notation at all.  It was necessary before SQL-92 became widely available; that has been the case for most of a decade, possibly longer now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try joining Likes table with itself using the rule `(l1.id1 = l2.id2) and (l1.id2 = l2.id1)`

Example:

```
SELECT
   a.name AS a_name,
   b.name AS b_name
FROM
   HighSchooler AS a
   INNER JOIN Likes AS l1
      ON (a.id = l1.id1)
   INNER JOIN Likes AS l2
      ON ((l1.id1 = l2.id2) AND (l1.id2 = l2.id1) AND (l1.id1 > l2.id1))
   INNER JOIN HighSchooler AS b
      ON (l2.id1 = b.id)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/44a07/6

Comment: i run the query but got a match up of people against themselves, but these were people in a two way relationship just that the match up didn't come out. Thanks though. here's a link to the data i'm using in case u want to look at it. https://dl.dropbox.com/u/100811396/highschool.sql

Comment: Oh sorry, it had an error in last join `(l2.id2 = b.id)` instead of `(l2.id1 = b.id)` and it didn't had `(l1.id1 > l2.id1)`. You can see it running on http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/44a07/6

Answer (score 1):

Your query is correct but it is using Cartesian product of tables which as you said is not optimal. When you write `select * from a,b` all the rows of a and all the rows of b are combined together to form a new table which has size(a)*size(b) rows. You are doing that with three tables so you are creating a huge table and then select from it a few rows that you want. Inner join can do this more efficiently.

```
SELECT
a.name AS name_a, b.name AS name_b
FROM
HighSchooler AS a
INNER JOIN Likes AS l1
ON a.id = l1.id1
INNER JOIN Likes AS l2
ON l1.id1 = l2.id2 AND l1.id2 = l2.id1 AND l1.id1 < l1.id2
INNER JOIN HighSchooler AS b
ON l1.id2 = b.id;
```

please see [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/faba6/19/0):

Comment: I think your SQL is fine (except perhaps the formatting, but that's partly a matter of taste).  I'm not sure where you see the Cartesian product in the original query.  The FROM t1 AS a, t2 AS b, t3 JOIN t3 ON ... notation is unusual (a hybrid of SQL-86 and SQL-92 notations) but the WHERE clause has the join conditions necessary to prevent it being a Cartesian product.

Answer (score 1):

The key self-join is between two references to the Likes table.  This then needs to be joined twice to the HighSchoolers table to get the names of the two people.

#### Step 1 Pairs of IDs where each likes the other

```
SELECT l1.id1, l1.id2
  FROM Likes AS l1
  JOIN Likes AS l2
    ON l1.id1 = l2.id2 AND l1.id2 = l2.id1;
```

This gives the list of pairs of IDs where each likes the other.

#### Step 2 Pairs of IDs where each likes the other without repeats

The only snag is that it gives each pair twice.  So, the trick is to note that in one of the two rows, the `id1` value is smaller than the `id2` value.  As a possibly beneficial side-effect, this eliminates anyone who likes themself.

```
SELECT l1.id1, l1.id2
  FROM Likes AS l1
  JOIN Likes AS l2
    ON l1.id1 = l2.id2 AND l1.id2 = l2.id1;
 WHERE l1.id1 < l1.id2
```

#### Step 3 Pairs of Names where each likes the other

Now to tidy it up with names:

```
SELECT h1.name AS name1, h2.name AS name2
  FROM (SELECT l1.id1, l1.id2
          FROM Likes AS l1
          JOIN Likes AS l2
            ON l1.id1 = l2.id2 AND l1.id2 = l2.id1
         WHERE l1.id1 < l1.id2
       ) AS p
  JOIN HighSchoolers AS h1 ON p.id1 = h1.id
  JOIN HighSchoolers AS h2 ON p.id2 = h2.id
```

`p` is mnemonic for 'pairs'.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your explanation is really elaborate, I do understand how it works now.Would it be possible to do without the sub-query and would that make it faster?

Comment: Answers: (a) yes, and (b) no.  The optimizer should reduce the query plan to the same operations.  You'd put the 'WHERE' clause in the sub-query into the ON condition for the join (though the optimizer would probably do that anyway).  It does depend a bit on the maturity and power of the optimizer — but this is routine stuff and I'd expect pretty much any DBMS to handle it.